# Android Admob throws exceptions

Tags: android, admob

I am receiving lots of exceptions from google. Exceptions are related with Admob.
Here is one of errors reported from google developer console:

These lines are same for all error reports.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.ads.util.g.a(SourceFile:439)
at com.google.ads.v.a(SourceFile:55)
at com.google.ads.internal.a.a(SourceFile:200)
at com.google.ads.internal.i.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(SourceFile:125)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:268)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:383)
```

Next lines are different /depending on report/

```
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my code:

```
if (ads_enabled)
{
    try
{
     AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
     m_adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    K_log.e(e.toString());
}
}
```

OnDestroy code:

```
try
{
    if (m_adView != null)
        m_adView.destroy();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
K_log.e("MainScreen -> m_adView.destroy()" + m_iCount + " " + e.toString());
}

super.onDestroy();
```

UPDATE:
Build is for min version 8, target version 13

Comment: Code works fine. Reported errors are 0.001% of served banners only.

Comment: Cannot debbug without more stacktrace or informations...

Comment: which SDK version are you using?

Comment: The last one. Build for min version 8, target version 13